# Common Lisp random dices

Tags: random, lisp, common-lisp, dice

I´m a beginner of c. Lisp and actually i´ve got some problems with my first code. The topic was a "dicegame" with random numbers. If you get two 1 you win or if you get two 6 you also win.

First i´ve worte this code:

```
(defun dice ()
  (+ (random 6) 1))


(defun dicegame (dice dice)
  (and (and (or
              (equal (print (dice)) 1)
              (equal (print (dice)) 6))
            (or
              (equal (print (dice)) 1)
              (equal (print (dice)) 6)))
       (or (equal (print (dice)) (print (dice))))))

(dicegame (dice) (dice))
```

it isn´t working. I get results with 6 numbers which are nil and i get results with for ex. 3 5 4 5 3 4 which are true. I don´t get that.

Than I wrote a new one which is working:

```
(defun dicegame-s (dice dice)
  (or (and (equalp (print (dice)) 1)
           (equalp (print(dice)) 1))
      (and (equalp (print(dice)) 6)
           (equalp (print(dice)) 6))))
```

My question is: why is the first one not working and the second one is working.

Thanks!

Comment: if you fix your indentation, things might become obvious. Emacs can help.

Comment: On your function DICEGAME: it has two arguments with the same name. Does that make sense? Additionally those arguments are unused. Instead you have repeatedly (dice) . What do you think (dice) does?

Comment: Define "working"?

Comment: Don't mix output with computations. First compute your values, then print them (or just look at them in your REPL without printing).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `dicegame-s` isn't *really* working. There are some problems with your code:

- #### all parameters of both `dicegame` functions have the exact same name

This should make the parsing of the code fail. You could name them `(dice-1 dice-2)` instead.

- #### you don't use the arguments you pass to your functions

In your functions, you use `(dice)`, which is a function call. So, instead of using the values given to the functions, you just roll a new dice each time!

So, when you write `(dicegame (dice) (dice))`, that’s when you are rolling the dice; the function only checks the values, and tells you if you have won.

- #### you `print` too much

The `print` function prints a value and returns it; that’s why you sometimes have up to 6 values with `dicegame`, since each `(print (dice))` writes its output. In fact, even in `dicegame-s`, if both dice are 6, 3 results will be printed.

Instead of calling `print` every time, you should call it once – at the beginning or the end of the function, or somewhere outside it.

## A working example

To correct the previous mistakes, you could do something like that:

```
(defun dicegame (dice-1 dice-2)
  (or (and (equalp dice-1 1)
           (equalp dice-2 1))
      (and (equalp dice-1 6)
           (equalp dice-2 6))))

(dicegame (print (dice)) (print (dice)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that there are so much "prints " this is onlying for me in this case. Like a control.

Comment: If I want to get a random dice value. For dicegame I have to call the function or not?  This arguments " dice" I don't need for my function because I can't call a function as an argument, right?

Comment: When you write `(dicegame (dice) (dice))`, you roll two dice, and pass their values to the function; they become `dice-1` and `dice-2` (or any name you've given)

Comment: And *yes* ! Of course you can pass a function as an argument and call it inside another one. But that’s probably *not* what you want to do here.

Comment: if i try to write it like you told me it doesn´t work I´m sorry. If i write (defun dicegame ((dice) (dice)) i only get errors

Comment: @Codeintelligent I added an example to help you.